# Can't fully remove color scheme's background in nvim

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, background

I want to keep my acrylic powershell background while using neovim, which requires blocking my colorscheme's background (currently trying sainnhe/everforest).

I've put `hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE` in init.vim, which has removed the background from my lines and console, but the background is still appearing in the space-filling tilde section. Is there something else I need to do to remove this?

[Here is how it looks currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxExs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also do the same for `EndOfBuffer`:

```
:hi EndOfBuffer guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE`
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost fixed it - I also had to do it for StatusLine as well.